# How does $\partial_\mu$ act on $A_\nu$ in the local structure equation for a curvature 2-form written in coordinates?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-algebras, curvature, connections, principal-bundles

Let $\pi: P \rightarrow M$ be a principal bundle and $s: U \rightarrow P$ be a local section where $U \subset M$ is open. Let $A$ be a connection 1-form and $F$ a curvature 2-form. Define $A_s = s^* A$ and $F_s = s^*F$ to be the local connection 1-form and local curvature 2-form respectively (i.e. the pullback of $A$ and $F$ under $s$).

Now suppose we have a chart on $U$ such that a basis for the tangent spaces above $U$ is given by $\{\partial \mu\}$. Thus in coordinates
$$A_\mu = A_s(\partial_\mu)\\
F_{\mu\nu} = F_s(\partial_\mu, \partial_\nu). $$

There is a theorem that states that in these coordinates the local curvature 2-form $F_s$ can be expressed as
$$F_{\mu\nu} = \partial_\mu A_\nu - \partial_\nu A_\mu + [A_\mu, A_\nu]. \tag{1}$$
Since $A_s$ is Lie algebra-valued, $A_\mu$ is an element in the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$. Here the base manifold $M$ is arbitrary, and $\partial_\mu$ is a basis element for the tangent spaces/vector fields over $U$, so how does it make sense for $\partial_\mu$ to act on $A_\nu$ as in (1)? Wouldn't $\partial_\mu$ have to be a tangent vector over the Lie algebra instead of $U$ for this to make sense?

Comment: If I have a map $f:\Bbb{R}^n\to V$, where $V$ is a vector space, does the symbol $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}$ make sense for $1\leq i\leq n$? If yes, what’s the definition? If no, why not?

Comment: @peek-a-boo If $f$ had instead been the map $f: V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ then we may define $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}$ as $\frac{\partial}{\partial r^i} (f \circ g^{-1})$ where $r^i$ is the $i$th coordinate in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $g: V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is a homeomorphism and $g = (x^1, \ldots, x^n)$, i.e. $x^i = r^i \circ g$. I'm not sure how to make sense of it for $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow V$.

Comment: ok if $V=\Bbb{R}$, what’s the definition?

Comment: @peek-a-boo Then this would be the ordinary limit definition of a derivative with respect to the $i$th coordinate.

Comment: write it out. does anything change if you replace $\Bbb{R}$ by $V$? and just in case this was the confusing issue: assume $V$ is a *normed* vector space over $\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo this would be $\frac{\|f(x_1, \ldots, x_i+h, \ldots, x_n) - f(x_1, \ldots, x_i, \ldots, x_n)\|_V}{\|h\|}$ assuming $V$ is normed.

Comment: well, that’s sloppy but yea, it’s the limit of the stuff inside the norms (and $\|h\|$ should be just $h$). The result is a map $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}:\Bbb{R}^n\to V$. So you see when the target is a (topological) vector space, there is no issue at all with defining derivatives. You can subtract, divide by a scalar, and take limits. The Lie algebra is just a vector space.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thank you, I now see how we may define a derivative when the target space is a Lie algebra. But what is confusing me is that the $\partial_\mu$ arise from the base manifold $M$, so shouldn't the $\partial_\mu$ act on tangent vectors in $TM$?

Comment: $\partial_{\mu}$ doesn’t act on tangent vectors it **is** the tangent vector (field). It can act on real-valued functions  $\tilde{f}:M\to\Bbb{R}$ almost by definition (depending on your textbook), or by the simple observation of your first comment: take the chart $(U,\phi)$ and consider $f_{\phi}=\tilde{f}\circ\phi^{-1}:\phi[U]\to\Bbb{R}$ and its various partial derivatives. My point is that making the *target* space a (topological/normed) **vector space** changes nothing. Things get complicated if you make the target a *vector bundle*, but that’s not the situation here.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Oh yes that was a mistype from me, sorry about that. I should have said $\partial_\mu$ is a tangent vector that acts on smooth functions $f: M\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. But from your comment it seems we may generalize this to say $\partial_\mu$ acts on smooth functions $f: M \rightarrow V$ where $V$ is a vector space? Thus taking the smooth coordinate map $\phi: M \rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ we may define $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}$ to be $\frac{\partial}{\partial r^i}(f\circ \phi^{-1})$ so that we are taking the derivative of a map from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $V$ as we defined earlier?

Comment: yes of course. And if you really don’t want to chart compositions anymore, then write $f=f^{\alpha}e_{\alpha}$ relative to a basis $\{e_{\alpha}\}$ on the target, where the $f^{\alpha}$ are smooth real-valued functions. Then define $\partial_{\mu}f:=(\partial_{\mu}f^{\alpha})e_{\alpha}$. Then check the definition doesn’t depend on the basis.

Comment: @peek-a-boo I think I get the general idea now. This term appears in the local structure equation as $\partial_\mu A_\nu$. Wouldn't this require $A_\nu$ to be a function from $U$ to $\mathfrak{g}$? Instead it is simply a Lie algebra element predetermined by $\partial_\nu$.

Comment: ? $A_{\nu}:U\to \mathfrak{g}$, so by our discussion above $\partial_{\mu}A_{\nu}$ is again a function $U\to\mathfrak{g}$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo I think this is where most of my confusion lies. I thought $A_s \in \Omega^1(U, \mathfrak{g})$ so that $A_\mu = A_s(\partial_\mu) \in \mathfrak{g}$ is a vector and not a function.

Comment: you should review the definition of vector-space valued 1-forms. FOr a usual 1-form $\omega$ on $U$ ($\omega\in\Omega^1(U)$), plugging in $\partial_{\mu}$ gives you a function $\omega_{\mu}=\omega(\partial_{\mu}):U\to\Bbb{R}$. If you consider vector-space values stuff then simply replace all the $\Bbb{R}$’s with $V$ ($\mathfrak{g}$ in your case)

Comment: @peek-a-boo After writing out my comment I think I realized my error. Of course any 1-form is a function over the base manifold, sorry about all the hold up this was very stupid of me. Thank you for all your help and your patience!

Comment: @peek-a-boo Sorry to comment on an older post, but I have been revisiting this question and based on our discussion above it seems that for this all to make sense we would need $\mathfrak{g}$ to be normed. That is, since $A_\mu: M \rightarrow V$, by using the coordinate map $\phi$ we have $A_\mu \circ \phi^{-1}: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathfrak{g}$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Then $\partial_\nu A_\mu$ can be interpreted as $\partial_\nu (A_\mu \circ \phi^{-1})$ which is by definition the limit of
$$\frac{\|(A_\mu \circ \phi^{-1})(x + h) - (A_\mu \circ \phi^{-1})(x + h)\|_\mathfrak{g}}{h}.$$
(I'm being a bit sloppy with the notation to make the writing easier but $h$ should only be added to the $\nu$th coordinate of $x$.) But this would require $\mathfrak{g}$ to be normed. How do we associate a norm to any Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$.

Comment: Yes, in general the target vector space must be a topological vector space so we can talk about limits there. Most commonly, a normed vector space. Finally, every finite-dimensional real/complex vector space has a norm, and all those norms give the same topology (i.e all norms on a finite-dimensional space are equivalent). In other words, because all norms work, you don’t have to explicitly mention which norm you’re working with.

Comment: Correct, no norm in numerator, but $e_{\nu}$ is NOT from the Lie algebra; it is the usual basis vector in $\Bbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thanks I caught that and deleted my comment. So in conclusion we have $$\partial_\nu A_\mu = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{(A_\mu \circ \phi^{-1})(x + h e_\nu) - (A_\mu \circ \phi^{-1})(x)}{h}$$ where $e_\nu$ is now a basis element of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Correct (space…)

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thanks again for all your help!